# The best way to execute java jar automatically everyday at a specific time

Tags: java, jar

I'm looking for the best solution to run a java jar automatically and everyday at a specific time.

The jar file will be executed (on windowd and linux palatform) only once manually. After it will be

executed automatically every day at a specific time.

Comment: Crontab is the word for Linux....I think for Windows you can use scheduled tasks as mentioned [here](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000785.htm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On linux:**

Add the script to crontab with the desired periodicity

**On windows:**

Add a scheduled task with the desired periodicity

The script content can be same on both the platforms, thanks to Java beauty. Something like this:

```
java -jar yourjar.name {optional input param}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use shell script on Linux and Batch file on Windows and schedule the script..to run whenever you want.